# Placing footnotes or endnotes at the end of the current paragraph

Tags: positioning, footnotes, endnotes, parnotes

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`parnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parnotes)

How can I get footnote or endnote text to appear right after the paragraph in which it was mentioned?

Update:

As my question lacks sufficient detail, I'll try to clarify.

- The goal is to place the notes closer to the reader and to have a document which flows from start to finish, rather than one that is interrupted continuously by footnotes.
- By "footnote" or "endnote", I mean anything with a cross-reference mark (e.g. "1") pointing to another place on the page (the end of the paragraph).

Update:

The provided answer greatly solves the initial problem quite well. It is, however, incompatible with a number of other options provided by addition packages, such as `footmisc` and its included options such as `para` and `stable`. The bounty will go to an extended solution which:

- Provides the ability to define the `mark` and `text` in different locations so that footnote marks can be placed within section titles (see `footnotemark` and `footnotetext` and `stable` options in `footmisc` for an example). E.g.:

  ```
  \begin{footnotepar}
  \section{This is a section title\footnotemark}
      \footnotetext{This is the text for a footnote which has a mark in the section title.}
      This is text in the paragraph.
  \end{footnotepar}
  ```
- Treats the footnote text as if it is no different from text within a standard paragraph and allows the text to behave in a similar manner (e.g. flowing into a paragraph, breaking at the end of the page). E.g.:

> 1 This is the text of the first footnote.  2 This is the text of
>
> the second footnote. 3 This is the text of the third footnote.
>
> 4 This is the text of the fourth footnote. 5 This is the text of

---

> the fifth footnote which partially appears on the top of the
>
> second page. 6 This is the text of the sixth footnote.

- Leaves points for uniformly controlling the size, font, and position of the footnote mark (the one appearing near the footnote), the footnote text itself, and the space after each footnote (e.g. placing `\newline` to go to a new line, or `\hspace` to add some space).
- Leaves points for uniformly enclosing an environment around each group of footnotes, for e.g., to enable the groups of footnote texts to be enclosed with `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}` (or other environments).

Comment: So, by "endnote" you refer to a footnote, but it should be placed immediately after the mentioned paragraph? If so, what should the formatting be? With/without a rule? Should it be flush left or right? `\footnotesize` or otherwise?

Comment: i don't see any way of doing this in a "stable" way.  what might be done is: extend endnotes to provide an environment, at the end of which something like \par\thenotes would be printed.  would need work on \thenotes not to produce a section title at the start of this stuff.  how would you expect these notes to look?  would you hope to have a separate document-wide set of endnotes (it would make life more difficult: the paragraph-style notes would have to be stored locally, whereas ordinary endnotes go to a file and are read in at the end),

Comment: Have you considered using margin-notes instead? Try `footmisc`'s `side` option.

Comment: _i_ thought endnotes had capabilities for this (i've only recently looked at it).  what am i missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may put each paragraph into a minipage, because minipages have their own footnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newenvironment{mpar}{\par\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{1em}%
}{\endminipage\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\blindtext
\begin{mpar}First example.\footnote{A note at the foot of the minipage}
\blindtext\end{mpar}
\begin{mpar}Second example.\footnote{A note at the foot of the minipage}
\blindtext\end{mpar}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Or you may define an environment, that does only copy the footnote feature of `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{footnotepar}{%
  \par
  \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}\def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}\c@mpfootnote\z@
  \let\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext
}{%
  \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else
    \vskip\skip\@mpfootins
    \normalcolor
    \footnoterule
    \unvbox\@mpfootins
  \fi
  \par\smallskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{footnotepar}Lipsum test:\footnote{lipsum is a
    package}\lipsum[2]\end{footnotepar}
\begin{footnotepar}Another\footnote{Not really another one}
  test:\footnote{This is a lipsum test}\lipsum[3]\end{footnotepar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: One caveat here would be that a `minipage` does not allow page breaks within.

Comment: @Werner: That's absolutely correct and should be considered. On the other hand it prevents footnote sign at the text of one page and footnote after the end of the paragraph at another page. Without more information from Village it's difficult to suggest a really good answer.

Comment: @Werner and @Schweinebacke: perhaps there is some exception to this and some way to allow a `minipage` to be broken at the edge of a page?

Comment: @Village: If added a second example with a new enviroment, that is not minipage but copies the minipage footnote feature. Nevertheless: It would be nice, if you'd edit your question to tell a little bit about what you are doing and what you are expecting.

Comment: Your second answer is very good. I've added a bounty to the question with some added details.

Answer (score 24):

> This is a stripped-down version of the code in the [`parnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parnotes) package.
>
> **NOTE** to anyone wanting to "do *x* after every paragraph": The proper way to make long-term changes to `\par` is through `\@setpar`, or by modifying `\@par` along with `\par`. Many LaTeX environments reset `\par` to `\@par` at end; see [source2e](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) chapter `ltpar.dtx`.

Here's a hack using `\g@addto@macro` to collect notes and place them in the main text flow later. Use `\parnote{TEXT}` to place a mark, then call `\parnotes` to put the notes in manually, anywhere you'd like. For a custom mark, use `\parnote[MARK]{TEXT}`.

There's also an `autopn` environment which sets parnotes automatically at the end of every paragraph by redefining `\par` and `\@par`. If you enter another environment while in `autopn` and you still want notes, you'll need to nest `autopn` within it. (Credit to Ahmed Musa)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
% Format for parnotes - \PN@notes@shape is blank (\relax) by default
\providecommand{\parnotefmt}[1]{\footnotesize%
                \PN@notes@shape\PN@narrower@optional\noindent #1}
% Format for parnote marks
\providecommand{\parnotemark}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
% Minimum vertical space before and after parnotes
\providecommand{\parnotevskip}{\medskipamount}
% Full command used between parnotes
\providecommand{\parnoteintercmd}{\hspace{1em plus 0.3em minus 0.2em}}

\global\def\PN@text{}
\global\newcount\c@parnotemark
\def\@PN@autopn{autopn}
\newif\ifPN@inparnotes
\def\PN@disable@indent{\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\let\PN@reset@optional\relax
\let\PN@mark@set\@arabic
\let\PN@narrower@optional\relax
\let\PN@notes@shape\relax

\newcommand\parnote{%
    \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
        \@ifnextchar [
            {\expandafter\PN@parnote@twoargs}%
            {\expandafter\PN@parnote@onearg}%
    \else
        \expandafter\PN@gobble@opt
    \fi
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\PN@gobble@opt{%
    \@ifnextchar [
        \PN@gobble@opt@@
        \@gobble
}
\def\PN@parnote@twoargs[#1]#2{\PN@parnote@real{#1}{#2}}
\def\PN@parnote@onearg#1{%
    \global\advance\c@parnotemark\@ne
    \begingroup\edef\@x{\endgroup\noexpand\PN@parnote@real%
                        {\PN@mark@set{\c@parnotemark}}}\@x{#1}%
}
\def\PN@gobble@opt@@[#1]#2{}

\long\def\PN@parnote@real#1#2{%
    \leavevmode
    \ifhmode\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak\fi
    \parnotemark{#1}%
    \ifhmode\spacefactor\@x@sf\fi\relax
    \unless\ifx\PN@text\@empty\g@addto@macro\PN@text{\parnoteintercmd}\fi
    \g@addto@macro\PN@text{\parnotemark{#1}\nolinebreak\thinspace#2}%
}

\newcommand\parnotes{%
    \unless\ifx\PN@text\@empty
        \expandafter\PN@parnotes@real
    \fi
}

\def\PN@parnotes@real{%
    \PN@inparnotestrue
    \unless\ifvmode\par\fi
    \nopagebreak\addvspace{\parnotevskip}%
    {\parnotefmt{\PN@text}\par}%
    \global\def\PN@text{}%
    \addvspace{\parnotevskip}%
    \PN@disable@indent
    \PN@reset@optional
    \PN@inparnotesfalse
}

\newenvironment{autopn}{%
    \let\PN@par\par
    \def\par{\PN@parnotes@auto\PN@par}%
    \def\@par{\PN@parnotes@auto\@@par}%
}
{\PN@parnotes@auto}

\def\PN@parnotes@auto{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\@PN@autopn
        \unless\ifPN@inparnotes
            \unless\ifx\PN@text\@empty
                \expandafter\PN@parnotes@real
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{0.3in}
\begin{autopn}
\noindent%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.

\section{On parnotes\parnote{Section note.}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.

Ut vel ante eros, in lobortis risus.

Lorem ipsum dolor.

\vspace{0.1in}
\noindent Notes inside \texttt{multicols}:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{autopn} % CHANGED: YOU MUST NEST autopn WITHIN ENVIRONMENTS
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Integer aliquet quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat.

New paragraph vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.
\end{autopn}
\end{multicols}
\end{autopn}

\noindent Notes outside \texttt{multicols}:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Integer aliquet quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat.

New paragraph vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.
\end{multicols}
\parnotes

\vspace{0.1in}
\noindent Notes break pages:\\[0.08in]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium. Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae. In aliquet tortor sed tellus
Porta et elementum diam sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
pulvinar pretium. Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae. In aliquet tortor sed tellus
Porta et elementum diam sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.} In nec neque vitae magna pulvinar
pretium.
\parnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Incredible! Please, go ahead and post a `parnotes` package to CTAN.

Comment: +1 for a new package ;-) -- See: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/which-questions-led-to-the-creation-of-a-new-package/1722#1722

Comment: Is it possible to get this to automatically reset the footnote numbering after each paragraph?

Answer (score 9):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{parnotes.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{parnotes}[2011/12/10 v0.0.1 Paragraph notes (Ahmed Musa)]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
\RequirePackage{combokeys}
\let\parnotesnosep\medbreak
\declarecombokeys[keyprefix=KVA,keyfamily=parnotes,macroprefix=pnt@]{%
  cmd/notecolor/black;
  cmd/noteformat/\@firstofone;
  cmd/notefont/\footnotesize;
  cmd/markformat/\@firstofone;
  cmd/vskip/\medskipamount;
  cmd/interskip/.5em;
}
\protected\def\declareparnotesformat#1{%
  \setkeys[KVA]{parnotes}{#1}%
}
\newcommand*\pnt@hook{}
\newcount\pnt@cnta
\@ifdefinable\parnote\relax
\protected\def\parnote#1{%
  \dkyifx\protect\@typeset@protect{%
    \global\advance\pnt@cnta\@ne
    \xdef\pnt@hook{%
      \dkyexpandonce\pnt@hook
      \begingroup
      \noindent
      \dkyexpandonce\pnt@notefont
      \noexpand\color{\pnt@notecolor}%
      \dkyexpandonce\pnt@markformat{%
        \noexpand\textsuperscript{\number\pnt@cnta}%
      }%
      \dkyexpandonce\pnt@noteformat{\unexpanded{~#1}}%
      \noexpand\hspace{\pnt@interskip}%
      \endgroup
    }%
    \ifvmode\else\unskip\fi
    \pnt@markformat{\textsuperscript{\number\pnt@cnta}}%
  }{}%
}
\protected\def\pnt@print{%
  \pnt@hook
  \global\pnt@cnta\z@
  \gdef\pnt@hook{}%
  \@saved@par
  \vspace{\pnt@vskip}%
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
\newenvironment{parnotes}{%
  \let\@saved@par\par
  \def\par{%
    \@saved@par
    \dkyifx\pnt@hook\@empty{}{%
      \vspace{\pnt@vskip}%
      \parskip\z@
      \pnt@print
    }%
  }%
}{%
  \dkyifx\pnt@hook\@empty{}{%
    \@saved@par
    \vspace{\pnt@vskip}%
    \parskip\z@
    \pnt@print
  }%
  \let\par\@saved@par
  \let\@saved@par\@undefined
  \par
}

\endinput
\end{filecontents*} 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,hyperref]{xcolor}
\declareparnotesformat{%
  noteformat=\textsf,markformat=\textsf,notecolor=ForestGreen,
  notefont=\footnotesize,vskip=\medskipamount,
  interskip=.5em
}

\begin{document}

\begin{parnotes}

\section{Let us start with a multicolumn}

\begin{multicols}{2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam \parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium. \parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus

\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.

\end{multicols}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.

\section{On parnotes\parnote{Section note.}}

\parnotesnosep
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.

Ut vel ante eros, in lobortis risus. Nullam pretium, ipsum sit amet
pharetra faucibus, felis diam aliquet sem, bibendum eleifend turpis metus
in ligula.

\vspace{2ex}
\noindent
Notes outside \texttt{multicols}:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.

\parnotesnosep

\noindent Notes inside \texttt{multicols}:

\begin{multicols}{2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus
\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.

\end{multicols}

\noindent Notes break pages:\\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam\parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium.\parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus

\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.
\end{parnotes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To avoid repetitive typing of `\parnotes`, something like the following is possible, but I haven't time now to look at the behavior of multicols in this case.

```
\def\beginparnotes{%
  \let\@saved@par\par
  \def\par{%
    \@saved@par
    \vspace{\parnotevskip}%
    \parskip\z@
    \ifx\PN@text\@empty\else
      \expandafter\parnotes
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\endparnotes{%
  \ifx\PN@text\@empty\else
    \@saved@par
    \vspace{\parnotevskip}%
    \parskip\z@
    \expandafter\parnotes
  \fi
  \let\par\@saved@par
}
\def\parnotes{%
    \parnotefmt{\PN@text}%
    \global\def\PN@text{}%
    \global\c@PN@t=\c@PN@n
    \vspace{\parnotevskip}%
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
```

Also, note the `\unskip` in the following:

```
\long\def\PN@parnote@real#1{%
    \global\advance\c@PN@t\@ne
    \g@addto@macro\PN@text{%
        \global\advance\c@PN@n\@ne
        \parnotemarkfmt{PN@n}~#1\hspace{\parnoteinterspace}%
    }%
    \unskip\parnotemarkfmt{PN@t}%
}
```

```
\begin{document}

\beginparnotes

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet
quam \parnote{Vitae mauris tempus!} consequat. In nec neque vitae magna
pulvinar pretium. \parnote{Nunc purus augue, egestas vitae lobortis at,
eleifend quis erat.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.} In aliquet tortor sed tellus

\parnote{Porta} et elementum diam sagittis.
\endparnotes
\end{document}
```