# How do I redefine a macro when any group begins, then again when that group ends?

Tags: tex-core, programming, e-tex

Okay, I know this is a pretty tall order, but I'm working on a package based on my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37682/9092), and I'm including Ahmed Musa's environment which redefines `\par`. The problems are:

1. Some environments (e.g., lists) use `\par` internally in ways that I don't want to touch.
2. Other environments (e.g., also lists) clobber my redefinition of `\par` *globally*.
3. There should be an easy way to exclude a set of paragraphs from the `\par` redefinition.

And it's all well and good to just explain in the documentation that the environment which redefines `\par` is for convenience only and that you should only really put flat text in it. But I was wondering if there was a better way.

---

**What I want to do**, if possible, is redefine the macro (really `\par`, but let's call it `\a=\a@new`) in such a way that when any environment or `{`-delimited group begins, it gets set to `\a@old`. And then when that *specific* environment or group ends, it should be set right back to `\a@new`, even if `\a` got globally redefined in the interim.

So, disregarding whitespace,

```
\def\a{old a}
\def\a@new{new a}

\a
\begin{redefa}
    \a
    {\a}
    {
        \gdef\a{\emph{weird} a}
        \a
        {\a}
    }
    \a
\end{redefa}
\a
```

Should give

> old a
>       new a
>       old a
>           *weird* a
>           *weird* a
>       new a
>   old a

Is this even remotely possible?

Comment: do you really need to `\gdef` this?  if you simply `\def` (or better, for latex, `\renewcommand{\a})` inside the group, then it will automatically go back at the end of the group to its definition before the group was opened.

Comment: There are a lot of groups inside package code. What you are asking to do is the direct opposite of the way groups usually work: I suspect that confusion lies on this path.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\gdef` is what other packages apparently do, and I'm trying to clean up after that. @JosephWright Yeah, I know this could mean sanitizing a hack with an *even worse hack*. But at least partly I'm asking this out of curiosity.

Comment: Getting `\a{\a}` to use two different defs for `\a` can only be done using `\currentgrouplevel` or `\currentgrouptype`. Reverting the `\gdef\a{weird}` at the end of the `{}` group is doable with `\aftergroup`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Holy crap, `\currentgrouplevel` is exactly what I wanted before I asked the question. If I combine that with some `everyhook` stuff, I think that'd put me well on my way to a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @rdhs: if you come up with a solution, post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **NOTE:** This is what I hacked together for my specific problem. If anyone comes up with a cleaner or more general answer, I'll accept that instead.
>
> Thanks to Bruno Le Floch for suggesting `\currentgrouplevel`!

`everyhook` provides a very secure way to append stuff to `\everypar`, which lets me run this at the start of *every paragraph*.

First, I check for environment changes using `\@currenvir`. Then, to defeat `{`-delimited groups, I also check that the paragraph is at the same `\currentgrouplevel` as `\begin{autopn}`. If both checks pass, `\par` gets redefined *once only* – the next time it is used, it assumes the value it had before `\begin{autopn}`.

But if the checks keep passing, `\par` keeps getting redefined. So if something `\gdef`'s `\par`, `\par` will just get redefined anyways once the group passes back to the `autopn` environment.

```
\RequirePackage[excludeor]{everyhook}

\newcount\PN@env@depth
\def\@PN@autopn{autopn}
\newenvironment{autopn}
    {\PN@env@depth=\currentgrouplevel}
    {\parnotes}
\PushPostHook{par}{%
    % check for environment changes
    \ifx\@currenvir\@PN@autopn
        % check for {-delimited groups
        \ifnum\currentgrouplevel=\PN@env@depth
            \let\PN@par@orig\par
            \def\par{%
                \PN@par@orig
                %
                % check again at the end of the paragraph in case the paragraph spans groups
                %
                \ifx\@currenvir\@PN@autopn
                    \ifnum\currentgrouplevel=\PN@env@depth
                        % the new code I wanted to inject
                        \parnotes
                    \fi
                \fi
                % restore the definition of \par; then everything just repeats next paragraph
                \let\par\PN@par@orig
            }
        \fi
    \fi}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `etextool` package adds begin- and end-hooks to all environments. You can use these to exclude certain environment, i.e. remove or change your definition accordantly. See the package manual for the details.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid when I come right out and say it, but I'm looking to do this for *all* environments, and `{`-delimited groups. Also, I've tried using `etoolbox`'s `\AtBeginEnvironment{list}{...}` to just get this behavior for lists, and it did nothing – I'll put a MWE in another question if this one is unresolvable.