# How to make footnote goes right after the text, not on the bottom of page

Tags: positioning, footnotes

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test\footnote{Test}
\end{document}
```

Now it like this:

[image: Footnote at the bottom of page]

And I want this:

[image: Footnote at the bottom of text]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34746/placing-footnotes-or-endnotes-at-the-end-of-the-current-paragraph

Comment: This question seems to ask something different, as I understand it the idea here is to place footnotes at the end of the text automatically, instead of manually using a `\parnotes` command of `autopn` environment as mentioned in the suggested duplicate. This may be done by hooking `\parnotes` to `\clearpage` and `\AtEndDocument` or something, may be useful to leave this question open for answers with this approach (or some other automatic method).