# customizing parnotes formatting

Tags: footnotes, parnotes

I would like to be able to use the package `parnotes`, which I recently learned about from [an earlier post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34746/placing-footnotes-or-endnotes-at-the-end-of-the-current-paragraph/37682), but customizing the formatting in my document.

1. I would like to be able to change the footnote hook to letters (a, b, c,...). Currently the only options available (as far as I could tell from `parnotes.sty`) are `arabic` (default: 1, 2, 3,...) and `roman` (i, ii, iii,...).
2. I would like to be able to make the footnote hook non-boldface even when the main text is boldface.

MWE:

`Test.\parnote{first parnote} \textbf{Test.\parnote{second parnote, called from text that is boldface}}`

[image: MWE results]

I would like to be able to:

1. replace "1" and "2" with "a" and "b"
2. make "2" not boldface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\renewcommand*\parnotemarkfmt[1]{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\alph{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Test.\parnote{first parnote} \textbf{Test.\parnote{second parnote, called from text that is boldface}}
\parnotes
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Thank you! When I used this solution, the footnote hooks came out not superscript but normal text. But it worked perfectly once I switched it around to this: `\renewcommand*\parnotemarkfmt[1]{{\normalfont\textsuperscript{\alph{#1}}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The version 3b of the package `parnotes` provides an option `alph` for using lower case alphabet characters at parnote marks. For using a non-boldface font, you can redefine the macro `\theparnotemark`. Since [esdd's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319789/23481) does not work anymore, here is an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[alph]{parnotes}

\let\oldTheparnotemark\theparnotemark
\renewcommand*\theparnotemark{\normalfont\oldTheparnotemark}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Test.\parnote{first parnote} \textbf{Test.\parnote{second parnote, called from text that is boldface}}
\parnotes
\end{document}
```