# parnotes: How to customize parnotes format locally?

Tags: formatting, parnotes

Based on [this answer from esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319789/78784) it is possible to customize the appearance of parnotes globally for a whole document.

However, I would like to customize the `parnotes` only for single usage in one single table, the rest should remain in standard format.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \parnoteclear
        Bla\parnote{First parnote} & Blub\parnote{Second parnote} & Blab\parnote{Third parnote} & Blob\parnote{Fourth parnote}\\
        \end{tabularx}
        \parnotes
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

How can I edit this command to let the `parnotes` appear in this style:

`A: This is the parnote text`

(Alphabetic letters instead of numbers, and these letters written in `\normalsize\alph` font instead of `\textsuperscript`)

---

**Update:**

Subham Soni mentioned to change the deprecated command to `\renewcommand{\parnotefmt}[1]{\normalsize}` - thanks! But I still don't know how to change the numbering to `\alph` and how to write the letters in normal text size?

Comment: I don't know which version of parnotes you are using. I get the following error provided in the parnotes documentation: You can no longer redefine `\parnotemarkfmt`. Use
`\theparnotemark` and `\parnotecusmarkfmt` instead

Comment: @subhamsoni: Thanks for your comment! But how can I let the parnote symbol appear in normal text size and not as `\textsuperscript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using parnotes 2016/08/15 rev. 3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\uglyparnote}{% local change
  \def\theparnotemark{\Alph{parnotemark}}%
  \def\parnotecusmarkfmt##1{~##1}%
  \long\def\parnotefmt##1{\normalsize%
                \PN@notes@shape\PN@narrower@optional\noindent ##1}%
  \long\def\PN@parnote@real##1##2{%
    \parnotemark{##1}%
    % Unless this is the first parnote in \PN@text, add a separator first
    \unless\ifx\PN@text\@empty\g@addto@macro\PN@text{\parnoteintercmd}\fi
    % Redefine \@currentlabel to the parnote label, so \label works
    \g@addto@macro\PN@text{\phantomsection\def\@currentlabel{##1}}%
    \g@addto@macro\PN@text{##1:~\nolinebreak\thinspace##2}%
 }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \uglyparnote
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \parnoteclear
        Bla\parnote{First parnote} & Blub\parnote{Second parnote} & Blab\parnote{Third parnote} & Blob\parnote{Fourth parnote}\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \parnotes
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would also like to write the `parnote` symbol behind the source position as normal text (no `textsuperscript`) - would this be possible? In the result it should look like "Bla A".

Comment: Possible.  Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I want to do this. :-) The reason is: I have a table with several columns including values. In the last column of this table I want to write some shortcut to an authors name who has published the belonging values. Unfortunately the authors names are too long to put it in the last column, therefore I want to place it below the table as `parnotes`. I hope this is legitim? :-)

Comment: There are a number of ways to achieve this effect, such as threeparttable or just \hyperlink and \hypertarget.

Comment: So you would recommend to not use this modified `parnote` but better use a different solution like mentioned in your comment?

Comment: It depends. \tablenotes also look like footnotes.  Why do you want to make your footnotes not look like footnotes?

Comment: The reason is: I want to place the notes directly below the table, not in the footer of the document. Furthermore, I want to display them in alph letters, because the last column will only contain the letters (referring to the belonging author). E.g.: Column 1: Name of property, column 2: Value of property, column 3: Source (= shortcut to authors name). If I would type it as a common `parnote`, the last column would only contain a `textssuperscript` 1 instead of a better readable A, B or C in normal text font. I hope you know what I mean. :-)

Comment: Ah, and furthermore: Usage of `threeparttable` is way more time consuming because you have to type the note number and then at the end of the table recall it with the same number. While with your `parnotes`-command you only have to type `\parnote{blabla}` and it will receive the letter and the correct referencing automatically.