# Package "threeparttable": What advantages does it provide?

Tags: tables, tabularx, threeparttable, notes, parnotes

In the past I have been using `tabularx`, `caption` and `parnotes` packages to design my tables. Now the user [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482256/78784) has mentioned the package [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable):

What advantages does `threeparttable` provide over the other packages mentioned?

---

My classic approach looked like that so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parnotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{This is the caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|}
        \parnoteclear
        Bla\parnote{First parnote} & Blub\parnote{Second parnote} \\
        \end{tabularx}
        \parnotes
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

- When does it make sense to go ahead with `threeparttable`?
- While common `parnotes` refer to their item identifiers automatically by themselves, in `threeparttable` I would manually have to type `42\tnote{1}` within the table and

  `\begin{tablenotes}
  \item [1] the first note ...
  \end{tablenotes}`

  below the table where I want to put my notes. This seems to be way more time consuming than just using `\parnote{This is a parnote}` and get everything done by itself?

Comment: Another advantage of `threeparttable` is that the caption width is set to the real width of the table, which maybe useful in some cases.

Comment: @Bernard: Hmm yes, but in the upper MWE this is just one more line of code `\captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth}` and it's done, isn't it?

Comment: How do you know the table width is *exactly* 0.8\textwidth? And if you decide to change the table font size, what do you do?

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks for your help! You said: "How do you know the table width is exactly `0.8\textwidth`?" - I've expected it will be exactly `0.8` when writing `\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}...`, or could there be some issues?

Comment: @egreg: I think the `parnotes` always keep attached to the table while common `footnotes` appear in the document footer, or am I wrong? At least, that is what the upper MWE does.

Comment: @egreg: You said: "By the way, don't abuse `tabularx`" - oh, did I do that in the upper MWE? I thought this is common usage of `tabularx`?

Comment: If you use `tabularx` the problem is different. Anyway, other packages measure the width of tables or figures, such as `floatrow`.

Comment: @Dave Don't make tables artificially wider than they are. The more white space in them, the less readable they are. Exception: tables that are almost equal to the column width may be made to fit it (with `tabular*`, usually).

Comment: the `tabularx` usage here is wrong, you have two `l` columns and no `X` but as egreg hints, it is better not to use `tabularx` here. Only use tabularx if you have tables with _paragraphs_  in the cells and `tabularx` can control the line breaking